# TYPO3 no data in frond end of extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

On TYPO3 8.7.3 using "extension_builder" I made a new simple extension, one table and two views: list, show. 
After installation, I added  new folder for my data, filled it with some records and inserted FE plugin with record storage page set to my folder. Problem is that no records are shown in FE, I see only field headers (translations are working fine).

(on older versions of TYPO3 (6.*.* and 7.*.*) i never had this kind of problem.

My templates: Templates/List.html

```
    <html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <f:layout name="Default" />

    This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects.

    If you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
    in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml:
      Resources:
        Private:
          Templates:
            List.html: keep

    Otherwise your changes will be overwritten the next time you save the extension in the extension builder

    <f:section name="content">
        <h1>Listing for Calendars</h1>

        <f:flashMessages />
        <f:debug inline="TRUE" >{_all}</f:debug>
        <table  class="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs" >
            <tr>
                <th>aa<f:translate key="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs_domain_model_calendars.calendar_name" /></th>
                <th><f:translate key="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs_domain_model_calendars.calendar_description" /></th>
                <th><f:translate key="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs_domain_model_calendars.calendar_colors" /></th>
                <th><f:translate key="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs_domain_model_calendars.calendar_category" /></th>
                <th><f:translate key="tx_pbjavrocalendarscatalogs_domain_model_calendars.calendar_category_sub" /></th>
                <th> </th>
                <th> </th>
            </tr>

            <f:for each="{calendarss}" as="calendars">
                <tr>     
                    <td>{calendars.calendarName}</td>
                    <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{calendars : calendars}"> {calendars.calendarDescription}</f:link.action></td>
                    <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{calendars : calendars}"> {calendars.calendarColors}</f:link.action></td>
                    <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{calendars : calendars}"> {calendars.calendarCategory}</f:link.action></td>
                    <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{calendars : calendars}"> {calendars.calendarCategorySub}</f:link.action></td>
                </tr>
            </f:for>
        </table>


    </f:section>
</html>
```

Layouts/Default.html

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <div class="tx-pb-javro-calendars-catalogs">
        <f:render section="content" />
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: That sounds like it should work. As you see some output, you have included the static templates. The only idea I have might be to try setting the storagePid in TypoScript setup instead: `plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid = <record folder ID>' (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#persistence). If that does not work, you might want to compare it with a newer TYPO3 version.

Comment: static TS is included - i see headers from fluid template in both two languages, i tried with storagePID in TypoScript. Very strange case, newer seen before. Now i`m looking in language setup, but all other extension works normal, as configured. If no translation default language is shown

Comment: You see the headers from the templates? That might point towards a Fluid Layout problem. Maybe you try to include a section in the Layout that does not exist in the template?

Comment: Could you show the used Layout?

Comment: generated by "extension_builder" no changes at this moment

Comment: Defeult.html <html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
 <div class="tx-pb-javro-calendars-catalogs">
  <f:render section="content" />
 </div>
</html>

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. Maybe put some `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` into the templates and some text of your own to the layout to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank for hint with debug, in debug I see in Extbase Variable Dump  as expected: 2 items - so data from DB is there, but not displayed by fluid? Am I right?

Comment: Then we found the suspect. Please add the template code to your question.

Comment: added, List.html and Default.html

Comment: Looks good, if the controller fills the variable "calendars*s*" - you checked that with the debug, did you?

Comment: yes, in debug I see that variable calendarss is filled with data array(2 items)
   settings => NULL
   calendars => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (3 items)
      0 => Piotrburda\PbJavroCalendarsCatalogs\Domain\Model\Calendarsprototypepersistent entity (uid=1, pid=34)
         calendarName => protected'Mocca' (5 chars)

Comment: Hmmm, that should work then.

Comment: Can I send you extension code?

Comment: No. That's not how far my support reaches ;) I am sure you can work it out from here.